# display parent field on django forms

Tags: django, web, django-forms

I'm developing a website based on Django. I'm creating forms now to be filled by the user.

First, I'm displaying a UserProfileForm to be filled out by the user, but I need to show the fields 'username', 'first_name' and 'last_name' that the User class have.

Second, I'm displaying a Form to create a Mascot Object, but I need to show an Image Field that it is inside of another Class called Image.

These are my classes(models.py):

```
class Mascot(models.Model):

    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    race = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    birth_date = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Image(models.Model):
    mascot = models.ForeignKey(Mascot)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to = 'pic_folder/%Y/%m/%d', default =     'pic_folder/None/no-img.jpg')
    is_profile_pic = models.BooleanField()
```

This is my form(forms.py):

```
class MascotForm(forms.ModelForm):

class Meta:
    model = Mascot
```

So, I need to display on the MascotForm the Image object.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply add an ImageFormField to the MascotForm and override the save method to create the Image instance also, like this:

```
class MascotForm(forms.ModelForm):
    image = forms.ImageField()

    class Meta:
        model = Mascot

    def save(self, commit=True):
        # mascot will have to save in this case, we don't pass commit
        mascot = super(MascotForm, self).save()
        image = Image.objects.create(mascot=mascot,
                                     image=self.cleaned_data.get('image'))
        return mascot
```

This would be one way. But a better way would be to have both forms in the view.
Create a ImageForm for the Image model and handle the save in the view:

```
    class ImageForm(forms.ModelForm):
        class Meta:
            model = Image
            fields = ('image',)

        def save(self, mascot, commit=True):
            image = super(ImageForm, self).save(commit=False)
            image.mascot = mascot
            if commit:
                image.save()
            return image

    def my_view(request):
        if request.method == 'POST':
            mascot_form = MascotForm(request.POST)
            image_form = ImageForm(request.POST, request.FILES)

            if mascot_form.is_valid() and image_form.is_valid():
                mascot = mascot_form.save()
                image = image_form.save(mascot)
                return redirect(....)
        else:
            mascot_form = MascotForm()
            image_form = ImageForm()
        return render(request, 'some_template.html', {
            'mascot_form': mascot_form,
            'image_form': image_form
        })
```

Comment: I'm having troubles with the first solution. The image field appears in the form but I can't upload the selected image. When I click the submit button the page just tell me that the Image Field is required, but do nothing.

Comment: I made it, I used the second solution and now I show the image in my form and upload it. Now I have another problem, when I submit the form the image file gets the default path.
image = models.ImageField(upload_to = 'pic_folder/%Y/%m/%d', default = 'pic_folder/None/no-png.png')

Comment: Can you remove the default and see what path it gets then?

Comment: I remove the default and now the form tells me that the Image Field is required.

Comment: And in case you don't upload image you want the value to be 'pic_folder/None/no-png.png'?

Comment: Yeap, or something like that

Comment: And if you set the default value on ImageField and upload an image it is saved in the default location?

Comment: It is not saved, the image takes the default url

Comment: does your form have enctype="multipart/form-data" ?

Comment: you cannot upload files without the form to have enctype set like that. That is why the image gets the default because the files aren't passed to the server

Comment: your form must look like `<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">`